# Too long question title in textbox possible

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, title

When asking a question the title textbox allows **300 characters max**. But If I try to post such a long question title I get an error after hitting the post button:

> title too long; maximum length **150**

Could you please sync that?!

Comment: I actually kind of prefer this method. By limiting it directly at 150, you may not notice if some of the characters get cut off at the end of the title due to the character limit, because your browser doesn't do anything to notify you that you've reached the limit other than just ignoring further character input. This may not be the *best* way to directly give users notice, but it's better than just letting the browser stop them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) said, the input box is larger than the limit to allow for copy/paste and whatnot.

We've recently added ajax checking (on blur) of title lengths (among other errors) to give users quicker feedback on this sort of error.

Looks like this:

[image: error box showing "Title cannot be longer than 150 characters" on a long title]

Comment: Good enough for me :)

Comment: This is inconsistent with the edit summary box (300/300).